# Speed of the Wind - from feet to mph

Tags: calculus

> The wind speed S in mph of a tornado at a distance d feet from its center defined by  $$ S(a,d, V)=\frac{aV}{0.51d^2} $$where $a =0.5$ and $V$ is the approximate volume of the tornado, in cubic feet. Approximate the wind speed $30 ~\text{ft}$ from the center of a tornado when its volume $12~000 ~\text{cubic feet}$ is ? mph (The wind speed 30 ft away from the tornado is ? mph.)

My work:

$ S(a,d,V)=\frac{aV}{0.51d^2}  =\frac{0.5(12000)}{0.51(30^2)} =13.071 ft$

The answer to be in mph. How to proceed with this? Do we need to convert from ft to a mile for volume and distance so that the answer in mph or in the final answer conversion to happen?

Could you please help?

Comment: @Matti, thank you for your kind suggestion. I loved it. This could probably be in the answer section instead of comment section. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem definition states that if $V$ is in cubic feet and $d$ is in feet, then the formula is correctly interpreted when $S$ is in miles per hour. (I know these units make no sense, but that's how approximations and engineering formulas sometimes work ...)

So as I see it, you have inserted the values in correct units to the equation, and the numerical result should be interpreted in miles per hour. So it's 13 miles per hour.

Comment: It just means that the constants $a$ and $0.51$ have appropriate units to make the conversion.